# How would one perform real-time syllable counting on audio input on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, audio, speech-recognition

I need to be able to count the number of syllables a speaker utters during a live recording. It should be noted that the speakers will not be using their native language and therefore most existing speech recognition solutions won't work. I've looked a little at CoreML, and I may be able to get access to speech corpora with the number of syllables coded, but I'm not sure how I would start training the model.

I'd also be happy with imperfect but generally consistent approaches that didn't use machine learning.

(This will be used in linguistics research in future)

In terms of naive solutions, I've found [this on Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=46221), but I'm not sure how it would be implemented in Swift (this sort of audio analysis is not my forte).

In terms of machine learning solutions, I found [this on GitHub](https://github.com/shreyas253/SylNet), but any attempts at porting the Tensorflow v.1 code to run in CoreML failed.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the technique used. If you want to get syllables from the audio that is definitively words, then another strategy would be to use a pre-trained speech-to-text model, like [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper), to get the transcript. From the transcript, you could run a simple algorithm on the text that counts the syllables in the transcribed text.

This method will not account for utterances that are faint, however. It will also take some wrangling to get it real-time, but it is is state-of-the-art transcription.

Another option is to use the Apple speech-to-text feature provided by the SDK. This tutorial, [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/transcribing-speech-to-text), will guide you to build a speech-to-text app with real-time transcription. Using the transcribed words, you can count the syllables from the transcript.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I failed to mention that the users will be using a second language, and that existing speech-to-text models do not work for many of them